# media_handle_upload() with 1 image under 1Mb chokes my server and returns timeout error

Tags: images, uploads

I'm struggling with 500 Timeout Errors when uploading images. Initially I was trying to upload 4 images at a time. Then I changed my code to upload 1 image at one time. If I `strln()` the $_SESSION I get 22872 bytes plus an image ofd less than 1Mb but the server still times out.

I've tried placing `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` at the top of my code right after `session_start()`. I also tried increasing `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` to 50000 and `max_input_vars` to 3000 while `post_max_size` is set to 64Mb and `memory_limit` and `upload_max_filesize` are set to 512Mb in the Options of my cPanel's PHP Selector tab (which I believe changes the values in php.ini).

I wrote a function that performs all the checks and then uses media_handle_upload() to upload the files. The function is called like thi:

```
if ( isset($_FILES["dlkimage1"]) && !empty($_FILES["dlkimage1"]["tmp_name"]) )
          fileUpload($_FILES["dlkimage1"],'dlkimage1');
```

When I look at the WP uploads folder I see the image gets uploaded but the browser returns `Request Timeout This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.`

Here is the function:

```
function fileUpload($file,$which_image) {
        global $images_upload_folder;
        global $max_file_size;
        define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
        $target_dir = $images_upload_folder;
        if ( isset($file) && !empty($file["tmp_name"]) ) {
            $filename = preg_replace('/\s+/','_', $file["name"]);   // remove white spaces from file name and replace with '_'
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename(cleanString(hyphenize($_SESSION['artist']).'_'.hyphenize($filename))); // where our file will live and what it will be called
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));   // image extension

            echo '<small>';

            // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
            $check = getimagesize($file["tmp_name"]);
            if( $check !== false ) {
                // echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
                $uploadOk = 1;

                // Check if file already exists
                if ( file_exists($target_file) ) {
                  echo '<br /><span class="error">A file with the same name already exists.</span>';
                  $uploadOk = 0;
                }

                // Check file size
                if ( $file["size"] > $max_file_size ) {
                  echo '<br /><span class="error">This file is too large. Please keep files under '.( $max_file_size / 1000000 ).'Mb.</span>';
                  $uploadOk = 0;
                }

                // Allow only certain file formats
                if ( !empty($file) && $imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
                  echo '<br /><span class="error">Only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.</span>';
                  $uploadOk = 0;
                }

                // Check if $uploadOk is set to 1 and, if so, proceed!!!
                if ( $uploadOk == 1 ) {
                    if ( !empty($file) ) {
                        $wp_image_array = array(
                            'post_author' => $_SESSION['writer_WP_id'],
                            'post_title' => $_SESSION['artist'],
                            'post_status' => 'inherit',
                            'post_name' => hyphenize($_SESSION['artist']).'_'.hyphenize($_SESSION['imagesuploaded'][$which_image]['name']).'_'.$which_image
                        );

                            $image_id = media_handle_upload(
                                        $which_image,       // file to upload
                                        $post_id,           // ID of image post
                                        $wp_image_array );  // image-specific data
                            if ( is_wp_error($image_id) )
                                echo '<br /><span class="error">There was an error uploading your file. - ' . $image_id->get_error_message() .'</span>';
                            else
                                echo '<br /><span class="success">Thank you for uploading your <b>'.str_replace('dlk','',$which_image).'</b>.</span>';

                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<br /><span class="error">Sorry, your file could not be uploaded.</span>';
                    $uploadOk = 0;
                }

          } else {
            echo '<br /><span class="error">This file is not an image.</span>';
            $uploadOk = 0;
          }

            echo '</small>';

        }
    if ( $uploadOk == 1 ) {
        // adds WHICH and WHAT image it is in the images uploaded array
        $_SESSION['imagesuploaded'][$which_image] = $file;  
        // add the WP image id into the session         
        $_SESSION['imagesuploaded'][$which_image.'_wp_id'] = $image_id;
        return $_SESSION['imagesuploaded'];
        unset($target_dir);
    }
}
```

Where am I failing?

To me it appears like the upload is happening but then the server times out on whatever else `media_handle_upload()` does but I'm new to the world of WP functions so I'm at a total loss

Comment: can you try testing your code with a single small upload instead of 4 big ones?

Comment: @mozboz it works with a single...

Comment: `$_SESSION` is a superglobal, so there's no need to `global` it. And, you said, "uses wp_handle_upload()" - but I see `media_handle_upload()` in the code. Also, why do you need to manually do the checks? `media_handle_upload()` can do all that for you.

Comment: @SallyCJ you are right about superglobal of course and apologies about referring to the wrong function... I meant `media_handle_upload()` - I will edit the post... I know I could have done the checks with `media_handle_upload()` but I had already written that function for the checks and I simply didn't know enough about how to do them with the WP functions because I'm new to WP programming (first project with WP functions)... what can I do about the fact that it gets stuck?

Comment: Ok, pardon me with that "do *all* that", but anyway, your code actually seems fine, except the `define()` part - you may only call it once, so try removing that from the function and define it elsewhere. Or is that line was just another typo in the question?

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ - I will try removing the `define` line and adding it at the top of the file after `session_start` and report back... I have a feeling it will fail anyway because if the issue was that line I should have gotten it an error, no?

Comment: I just tried it @SallyCJ and I still get `500 - Request Timeout
This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.` :-(

Comment: Actually, I think I wasn't really paying attention to the "timeout" in the error code/message. So instead of trying to fix the error (by doing things like increasing the max execution time), you can avoid it by using AJAX to upload each file after the other is complete, i.e. process one at a time. And that's actually how the default WordPress media uploader works. But for what it's worth, you can try uploading four images at once with each one in between just 1-50 KB in size...

Comment: And btw, that `define()` thing is still an issue even if it doesn't break the whole page/execution. You shouldn't redefine constants and if you enabled debugging, I bet you'd get a notice about that issue.

Comment: @SallyCJ I took your advice and tried with 4 images of 25kb each and it worked right away... when I looked in the uploads folder the 4 images (and all the resized versions of them) where all there... would you be so kind and direct me to an ajax example of how to do what you suggest (and what the WP uploader does)? I've never programmed anything in AJAX before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109414/discussion-between-sally-cj-and-marcnyc).